# Display post's category name as a part of shortcode in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to display post's category name but it's not working.
How could I get this to work?
I've wrote the following in function.php

```
function wptuts_recentpost2($atts, $content=null){
$getpost = get_posts( array('number' => 1, 'offset' => 1) );
$getpost = $getpost[0];
$return = get_the_post_thumbnail($getpost->ID) . "<br /><a class='post_title' href='" . get_permalink($getpost->ID) . "'>" . $getpost->post_title . "</a>.$getpost->cat_ID. <br />" . $getpost->post_excerpt . "…";
$return .= "<br /><br />"; 
return $return;
}
add_shortcode('newestpost2', 'wptuts_recentpost2');
```

Comment: Does the original `$getpost` array contains the `$cat_ID` parameter? Please share all the relevant code (but [keep it minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible) so that we can help out.

Comment: Maybe use $category = get_the_category(); than $cat_name  = $category[0]->cat_name; will do the trick?

Comment: @cabrerahector Just added the whole thing! Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [get_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) function returns an array of post objects which don't include info on their taxonomies.

As @condini-mastheus correctly points out, you'll need to use [get_the_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) to obtain the category of each post:

```
function wptuts_recentpost2( $atts, $content=null ){

    $getpost = get_posts( array('number' => 1, 'offset' => 1) );
    $getpost = $getpost[0];
    $category = get_the_category( $getpost->ID );

    $return = get_the_post_thumbnail($getpost->ID) . "<br /><a class='post_title' href='" . get_permalink($getpost->ID) . "'>" . $getpost->post_title . "</a>" . $category[0]->cat_name . "<br />" . $getpost->post_excerpt . "…";
    $return .= "<br /><br />";

    return $return;

}
add_shortcode('newestpost2', 'wptuts_recentpost2');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I get syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Comment: Fixed, you commented before I managed to update the answer @HirohitoYamada :P

Comment: Thanks! All fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
$category = get_category($getpost->cat_ID)
```

and than replace

```
$getpost->cat_ID
```

to

```
$category->name
```

Comment: [get_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category/) returns data on a given category. In this case, you want to use [get_the_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) instead.